# Webpack Chunks In Separate Folder

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I want to implement code-splitting feature in my app. I split my app by routes and for every route I user `require.ensure` to import component. I try to put all chunks in chunk folder, so I change output in config file:

```
output: {
   filename: "chunks/bundle[name].js"
}
```

But I got 404 error.

> Error: Loading chunk 2 failed at
>   HTMLScriptElement.onScriptComplete

So I leave it in folder where I have bundle file:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = {
    entry: "./js/app.js",
    output: {
        filename: "./bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: "vue-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader:"babel-loader"                
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?\S*)?$/,
                loader: "file-loader?name=element-ui/[name].[ext]"
            }       
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ ".json", ".js", ".vue", ".css" ]
    },
    watch: true
};
```

An now works, but I got chunk structure like this: [folder chunk structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pD1S.png). How can I move all that chunks in only one folder. And is this proper way of using code-splitting feature.

I think I'm missing something.
Please help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all include path module at the top of `webpack.config` file.:

```
var path = require("path");
```

Because you have multiple chunk files, your output point need to have `filename`, and `chunkFilename` property with `[name]` or `[id]`. Problem with file structure is that you didn't define publicPath:

```
output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: 'dist/',
    chunkFilename: '[name].js'
}
```

Now every chunk file and other bundles like `main.js`, `vendor`, `manifest` file will be in `dist/` folder.
Here is example of [webpack.config.js](https://jsfiddle.net/acrqq5hu/) file

Answer (score -1):

If you want to separate chunk files from the entry, you can try the following configuration:

```js
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    // ...
    output : 
}
```