# Is it possible set the output folder runtime using webpack API

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

Is it possible to override the `output.path` programmatically using the WebPack API?

Here's my output configuration:

```
var output = {
  path: './',
  filename: '[name].js'
};
```

I have six chunks and need to group five of them in `./dist/app` and one in `./dist`
I would be able to check the chunk name and based on that set the path

Comment: How about deriving both `chunkFilename` and `path` from a common prop e.g. `[name]` as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42413363/4636715

Comment: @vahdet i already considered that option but is not the solution for me.
I have six chunks and need to group five of them in `./dist/app` and one in `./dist`